# Why are the methods from my C# DLL missing?

Tags: c#, mfc, tlb

I am trying to learn how to write a C# DLL and call it from a MFC application.

Here is a bit of the DLL code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace MSATools
{
    public class MSAToolsLibrary
    {
        public MSAToolsLibrary()
        {
            _PublisherData = new PublisherData();
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        private string _strPathXML;

        public void SetPathXML(String strPathXML)
        {
            _strPathXML = strPathXML;
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        private PublisherData _PublisherData;

        public void SavePublisherData()
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_strPathXML))
            {
                x.Serialize(writer, _PublisherData);
            }
        }

        public void ReadPublisherData()
        {
            _PublisherData.Publishers.Clear(); // Reset

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_strPathXML))
            {
                _PublisherData = (PublisherData)x.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        public void AddPublisherData()
        {
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Andrew", "Andrew notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Rachel", "Rachel notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Joshua", "Joshua notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Finlay", "Finlay notes");
        }
    }
}
```

I ticked the options to register it as a interop and I have a TLB file.

I then went into a new MFC project and followed a tutorial to create a class from a TLB file. But all it created was:

```
// Machine generated IDispatch wrapper class(es) created with Add Class from Typelib Wizard

#import "D:\\My Programs\\2017\\MSATools\\MSATools\\bin\\Release\\MSATools.tlb" no_namespace
// CMSAToolsLibrary wrapper class

class CMSAToolsLibrary : public COleDispatchDriver
{
public:
    CMSAToolsLibrary() {} // Calls COleDispatchDriver default constructor
    CMSAToolsLibrary(LPDISPATCH pDispatch) : COleDispatchDriver(pDispatch) {}
    CMSAToolsLibrary(const CMSAToolsLibrary& dispatchSrc) : COleDispatchDriver(dispatchSrc) {}

    // Attributes
public:

    // Operations
public:


    // _MSAToolsLibrary methods
public:

    // _MSAToolsLibrary properties
public:

};
```

I am clearly missing something here. I was anticipating seeing my public methods:

```
SetPathXML
ReadPublisherData
SavePublisherData
AddPublisherData
```

What have I missed?

This is how the classes look in the IDE (the MSATools DLL project):

[image: Classes]

### Update

I tried to add an interface to my C# library and I must have done something wrong:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MSATools
{
    [Guid("xxxxxx")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    public interface iInterface
    {
        void SetPathXML(String strPathXML);
        void SavePublisherData();
        void ReadPublisherData();
        void AddPublisherData();
    }

    [Guid("xxxx")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class MSAToolsLibrary
    {
#region iInterface Members
        public MSAToolsLibrary()
        {
            _PublisherData = new PublisherData();
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        private string _strPathXML;

        public void SetPathXML(String strPathXML)
        {
            _strPathXML = strPathXML;
        }

        [XmlIgnore]
        private PublisherData _PublisherData;

        public void SavePublisherData()
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(_strPathXML))
            {
                x.Serialize(writer, _PublisherData);
            }
        }

        public void ReadPublisherData()
        {
            _PublisherData.Publishers.Clear(); // Reset

            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(_PublisherData.GetType());
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_strPathXML))
            {
                _PublisherData = (PublisherData)x.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }

        public void AddPublisherData()
        {
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Andrew", "Andrew notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Rachel", "Rachel notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Joshua", "Joshua notes");
            _PublisherData.AddStudent("Finlay", "Finlay notes");
        }
#endregion
    }
}
```

It compiles OK. But when I go to Visual C++ MFC and go to add a class from TypeLib and choose this TLB file **nothing** shows in the list as available.

Confused.

### Update 2

I decided to try and create my own class as a wrapper:

```
#pragma once

#import "D:\\My Programs\\2017\\MSATools\\MSATools\\bin\\Release\\MSATools.tlb" raw_interfaces_only named_guids

class CMSATools
{
public:
    CMSATools();
    ~CMSATools();
    void SetPathXML(CString strPath);
    void Test();
};
```

And:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "MSATools.h"


CMSATools::CMSATools()
{
}


CMSATools::~CMSATools()
{
}


void CMSATools::SetPathXML(CString strPath)
{
    MSATools::iInterfacePtr     pInterface = NULL;

    HRESULT         hr;
    hr = pInterface.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSATools::MSAToolsLibrary));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CComBSTR    bstrText = strPath.AllocSysString();
        pInterface->SetPathXML(bstrText);
    }
}


void CMSATools::Test()
{
    MSATools::iInterfacePtr     pInterface = NULL;

    HRESULT         hr;
    hr = pInterface.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSATools::MSAToolsLibrary));

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        CComBSTR    bstrText(_T("d:\\TestStudents.XML"));

        pInterface->SetPathXML(bstrText);
        pInterface->AddPublisherData();
        pInterface->SavePublisherData();
    }
}
```

It compiles and I can see the methods with VisualAssist:

[image: Syntax]

But for some reason, `hr` does not pass the `SUCCEEDED` call.

### Update 3

If I rebuild the DLL as x64 and rebuild the MFC EXE as x64 then I get an exception:

[image: Exception]

### Update 4

I had to add into my MFC application `InitInstance`:

```
::Coinitialize(true);
```

And in `ExitInstance`:

```
::CoUnitialize();
```

Then the exceptions went away.

Comment: by default AssemblyInfo has [assembly: ComVisible(false)], either change it to true or mark the methods you want as comvisible. mind you I too am relatively new to COM

Comment: @prof1990 I already have the "Make assembly COM-Visible" ticked and I confirm it is set to `true` in the `cs` file. But I have not marked any methods in any way.

Comment: Which tutorial to create a class from a TLB file follow you?  I'm interested.

Comment: @TomTom I haven't really followed a tutorial. Visual Studio creates a class from the TLB when you import it into your MFC or other project. Have you Googled for a tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this modification, generating a new guid with VS, because i do not remember if it is auto written in another file.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
[Guid("xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx")]
[ProgId("MSAToolsLibraryClass")]    
public class MSAToolsLibrary
{
...
```

**EDIT**

Ensure your Assembly.cs has a line like this:

[assembly: Guid("xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx")]

Comment: Ok, I did that, and also changed my class to inherit from the iInterface class. But the derived class that is created in Visual C++ still only has the basic content.

Comment: Are you compiling for the right platform? AnyCPU is delusive, try again compiling for x86 / x64. I have not VS installed now, but i worked creating DLLs for use in Visual Basic 6 and i can swear you this is not very difficult, some little detail is missing.

Comment: Did you try compiling for x86? Due compatibility issues we did not compile for x64, customers used both 32 & 64 SOs.

Comment: Ok, if I build the DLL as x86 and the MDX EXE as Win32, I do not get an exception. But the hr has a negative value.

Comment: Has your Assembly.cs a line like i edit in the answer?

Comment: Yes. The GUID value there and the GUID value in the CS file are not the same though.

Comment: Try comment MSAToolsLibrary constructor and move constructor code to public void Init() method. I think i remember there were problems with this and about polymorphism, but maybe were VB issues, not COM issues. Anyway, try that, comment constructor and call Init method.

Comment: I had to add `CoInitialize` etc to my MFC `InitInstance`

Comment: You should try a test as simple as possible with foo classes. If COM has limits about constructors there is no choice.

Comment: Sure. I have it working now. I needed the interface class in the DLL and I needed the CoInitialize etc...